# How to make a sidebar scrollable in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dashboard

This is what I want:[Dashboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctlWA.png)

But this is what I have:[Current State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjKp8.png)

I want the sidebar to be full-height even if there are only one or two items. Same for the main content section. If the number of items go beyond the screen, the sidebar should become scrollable, but the main content shouldn't scroll. Similar to the youtube home screen. I tried putting the sidebar height as 100vh, but it was going beyond and the whole page was becoming scrollable.

This is my current code:

UserDashboard.js

```
function UserDashboard() {
  return (
    <>
        <Header />
        <main>
          <Sidebar />
          <Main />
        </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

UserDashboard.css

```
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Sidebar.js

```
function Sidebar() {
 return (
    <section className="sidebar">
      <SidebarItem
        to="/"
        title="Profile"
        selected={selectedItem === "Profile"}
        onClick={() => handleItemClick("Profile")}
      />
      <SidebarItem
        to="/calendar"
        title="Calendar"
        selected={selectedItem === "Calendar"}
        onClick={() => handleItemClick("Calendar")}
      />
      <SidebarItem
        to="/leave"
        title="Leave"
        selected={selectedItem === "Leave"}
        onClick={() => handleItemClick("Leave")}
      />
    </section>
  );
}
```

Sidebar.css

```
.sidebar {
    flex: 0.2;
    background-color: #0B2853;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Main.js

```
function Main() {
  return (
    <section className="main-content">
      <section className="main-container">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/leave" element={<Leave/>} />
          <Route path="/leave/applyleave" element={<ApplyLeave />} />
        </Routes>
      </section>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Main.css

```
.main-content {
    flex: 0.8;
}

.main-container {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    height: 96%;
    margin: 1%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Then, height: 100%; to your sidebar should give the full height.

Hope is that what you want :)

Comment: This did not resolve my issue